# Modify the output of the grep command

Tags: vim, grep

Is it possible to change the
output format of grep command from

```
./path1/path2/file1.cc:1646:
```

to

```
+1646 ./path1/path2/file1.cc
```

I am using vim editor and this modification will help me 
to edit file directly using

```
:edit +1646 ./path1/path2/file1.cc
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why not just use the quicklist? there you can just press enter, and you will get to the right line number. And you don't even have to leave vim. If you somehow need to use grep, you can format the output with sed.

Comment: I do not leave vim, just moving it to background session!

Comment: maybe have a look at vimgrep or even ack.vim. Else try to use sed. (`grep ... | sed ...`). Once you have a problem with the sed regex, SO will be a good place to ask ;-)

Comment: Have you tried using `gF` from within vim when cursor is on the file path? That will be quicker than `:edit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like you are:

- backgrounding Vim,
- grepping in your shell,
- copying a filename and number,
- foregrounding Vim,
- starting an ex command,
- putting the filename and number,
- running the ex command to edit that file at that line.

This is incredibly wasteful.

You should use the built-in `:help :grep` command instead:

```
:grep foo *.js
:cwindow
```

Comment: after built-in grep command, I get a list of results. How can I get to a specific result?Thanks!

Comment: You click on it.

Comment: automatically, activates the first result!

Answer (score 1):

If you need this for opening a file and positioning at particular number, you can do

```
$grep -rnI 'expression' ./ > out.txt
$vim out.txt
```

then use `gF` on a line, that will take you file, provided `path` is set properly, and line number and return back to `out.txt` using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>

BUT this is wasteful, you can use

```
:grep expression **/*.cc
:cwindow
```

More at `:help quickfix` and `:help cw`